# Query in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

i am creating a query in Microsoft Access, i have 3 tables, Income, Expenses, costumers. i want to have the history of the costumer, his records on the expenses and his records on income, in one table. He has two records as income and 1 record as expenses. As a result i take the two records of income but the one record of expenses is duplicated and is not null as i expected when i run the query. can you please help me?
thank you!
[image: Query design]

[image: Query result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `UNION` query.

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CUsID, tblCustomer.CusName, tblIncome.Income, null as [Expense]
FROM tblIncome INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON tblIncome.CusID = tblCustomer.CUsID

UNION ALL

SELECT tblCustomer.CUsID, tblCustomer.CusName, Null AS Income, tblExpense.Expense  as [Expense]
FROM tblCustomer LEFT JOIN tblExpense ON tblCustomer.CUsID = tblExpense.CusID
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i amtrying but i can't manage it.

Comment: This is the query  SELECT Έξοδα.Αναγνωριστικό, Έξοδα.Ημερομηνία, Έξοδα.Πελάτης, Έξοδα.Ποσό, Έξοδα.Αιτιολογία, Έξοδα.[Τα εισέπραξε ο], Έξοδα.[Αριθμός απόδειξης], Έξοδα.Ταμείο, Έξοδα.Τίτλος
FROM Έξοδα ;


UNION ALL

 SELECT Έσοδα.Αναγνωριστικό, Έσοδα.Ημερομηνία, Έσοδα.Πελάτης, Έσοδα.Ποσό, Έσοδα.Αιτιολογία, Έσοδα.[Τα εισέπραξα από], Έσοδα.[Αριθμός απόδειξης], Έσοδα.Ταμείο, Έσοδα.Τίτλος
FROM Έσοδα ;  i have solve the duplicate issue but i cant manage to add the column wich is empty when there is not value like your example

Comment: Update:   SELECT Έξοδα.Αναγνωριστικό, Έξοδα.Ημερομηνία, Έξοδα.Πελάτης, Έξοδα.Ποσό, Έξοδα.Αιτιολογία, Έξοδα.[Τα εισέπραξε ο], Έξοδα.[Αριθμός απόδειξης], Έξοδα.Ταμείο, null as [Έσοδα]
FROM Πελάτες INNER JOIN Έξοδα ON Πελάτες.Αναγνωριστικό = Έξοδα.Πελάτης;
UNION ALL

SELECT Έσοδα.Αναγνωριστικό, Έσοδα.Ημερομηνία, Έσοδα.Πελάτης, Έσοδα.Ποσό as [Έσοδα], Έσοδα.Αιτιολογία, Έσοδα.[Τα εισέπραξα από], Έσοδα.[Αριθμός απόδειξης], Έσοδα.Ταμείο, null as Έξοδα
FROM Πελάτες INNER JOIN Έσοδα ON Πελάτες.Αναγνωριστικό = Έσοδα.Πελάτης;    but the values from income appearing in the expenses (Εξοδα) column